# Append number to list in Redis

Tags: redis

Let's say I have the following result in Redis:

GET YEARS

> [2010, 2011, 2012, 2013]

How can I add a another year to this list? I tried RPUSH and SADD but they are not working.

Comment: Please post your attempt/error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are able to get the value of `YEARS` by GET command. This implies that it is saved as [String](https://redis.io/topics/data-types#strings) data type. If you want to continue using String, you would have to

1. get the String value (of `YEARS`)
2. concatenate another year, and
3. save the new String (in `YEARS`) by SET or similar command

Or, instead of String, you can use

- [List](https://redis.io/topics/data-types#lists) data type, where you would be able to add another year by a single RPUSH/LPUSH command
- [Set](https://redis.io/topics/data-types#sets) data type, where you would be able to add another year by a single SADD command

Comment: I don't think that steps 1-2-3 specified in the first part of your answer are thread-safe. Are they? Let's say, there's key1:[a] initially. Request1 wants to append b, Request2 wants to append c. Both fetch [a] and depending on which finishes first, we end up either with [a,b] or [a,c]. Is this mitigated in case of LPUSH/RPUSH/SADD?